# Is it possible to mount an MFM drive without an ISA slot?

Tags: hard-drive

As the title indicates, is there a way to connect a vintage MFM 5.25 form factor hard drive to a modern system that lacks an ISA slot (hence no MFM controller) ?

I know its a long shot, but ideally I would like some hodgepodge of adapter(s) that will let me mount one of these drives under Windows 7 for some benchmarking.  For that matter, I wonder if Windows 7 would even address such a device without some degree of 3rd party hackery/emulation?

Comment: I think the ISA is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to connect a controller using a USB to ISA board, such as http://www.arstech.com/item-USB-2-0-to-ISA-card-usb2isa.html

I believe Linux 2.6 does have drivers for MFM controllers, whereas I find it highly unlikely that Windows 7 would support MFM controllers... Good luck though!